# Workflow for a documentation translation repository

Tags: git, workflow

Consider the following documentation repository : https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs
There is a repository for the french version of this repository https://github.com/symfony-fr/symfony-docs-fr

How would a french contributor use git to:

- be aware of the modifications made on the english repository
- be sure to translate every word when sort-of-merging these changes?
- easily work with other contributors?

This has already been discussed [here](https://github.com/symfony-fr/symfony-docs-fr/issues/171), but we lack insight from experienced git users.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting, here's what I can think of quickly:

As mentioned in the github discussion:

You could have an upstream branch of the original documentation, and with that branch you can see which files are modified on any given day.
If you have one person in charge of the French translation, that person could keep an eye on the original branch, either by have a separate repository, or using Github's feeds.

Working with other contributors would mean setting a set of rules, if somebody starts translating a document there needs to be an issue. The translation would be a separate branch, aka feature branch. This branch could be pushed to github for review or modifications by others before merging it into the master branch.

I can't really think of way to make sure that every word that has been changed in the original repo has been translated. A though that some people might have is to translate the diffs, but the problem is that the grammar between French and English differs, making it near impossible to use the patches from the original.
Something you could do is create an issue at the French repo for every merge that occurs in the original repo, you reference the original commit in the French issue.